# Fanfic: Picard on a mission in the Star Wars galaxy

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, star-trek, fan-fiction

Some time between 1999 and 2004 I read a fan-written Star Trek - Star Wars crossover, unsurprisingly called Trek Wars, on the Web. I'm looking for a copy of it, or the author's name.

Some points I remember:

- Q persuaded Picard to help clean up the mess left by a Q experiment
- Picard recruited a bounty hunter who turned out to be a disgraced Jedi who'd stumbled through a wormhole
- The Force could not be felt in the Star Trek galaxy because it was all being used to contain a great evil (implied to be the false god from ST V)
- Picard's crew took a stolen Enterprise through the same wormhole to the Star Wars universe
- They joined a Rebel ship and went to rescue Luke Skywalker
- There was a lot of comparison of technologies and tactics
- Picard used a light sabre to free a prisoner

Comment: I found a YouTube video with the name Trek Wars which was uploaded 4 years ago: https://youtu.be/U0nnkW06KPA

Comment: Not the one sadly. I came across a few different works called Trek Wars while searching., some are pretty good.